# Javascript: automated scrolling on end make reverse animation

Tags: javascript, css

I have a simple code that will automatically smoothly scroll horizontally div#boo.

I'm trying to make on end the reverse animation. So when scrolled div#boo will be scrolled on the end the animation will be reversed and div will be automatically smooth scrolled on the opposite side to the begining.

This animation need to be bouncing and make animation whole time again and again.

```js
var boo = document.getElementById("boo");
function move() {
  boo.scrollLeft += 1;
}
setInterval(move, 20)
```

```css
p {
width: 1600px;
}

div {
overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="boo">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque consequuntur quas libero voluptatem recusandae necessitatibus inventore, velit aperiam, incidunt ut eos distinctio, ducimus magnam veritatis tenetur autem debitis iusto dolorum?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if you are at end, clear interval and set it again reverse

```js
var boo = document.getElementById("boo");
function move() {
  boo.scrollLeft += 1;
  if(boo.scrollLeft >= (1600 - boo.offsetWidth)){
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(moveReverse,5);
  }
}
function moveReverse() {
  boo.scrollLeft -= 1;
  if(boo.scrollLeft <= 0){
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}
interval = setInterval(move, 5)
```

```css
p {
width: 1600px;
}

div {
overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="boo">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque consequuntur quas libero voluptatem recusandae necessitatibus inventore, velit aperiam, incidunt ut eos distinctio, ducimus magnam veritatis tenetur autem debitis iusto dolorum?</p>
</div>
```